# iOS Swift: Passing data between views and completion handlers

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `viewControllers`: LoginViewController and NextViewController. Now when the app runs the LoginViewController runs a completion handler that takes care of the authentication with HTTP request, and after it's done, it calls another closure that gets the necessary user data.

I don't know how to pass that data that i get back from the callback function into the NextViewController to display it because I have no way of knowing when the data becomes available as it is running an HTTP request in the background.

So how should I present the data when it becomes available?

I know I can just call the second callback method for getting the user information inside the nextViewController, but that makes the app slower.

Here's example code:

```
class Methods: NSObject {

    //Singleton
    class func sharedInstance() -> Methods {
        struct Singleton {
            static var sharedInstance = Methods()
        }
        return Singleton.sharedInstance
    }


    private func GETMethod(callBackMethod: (Success: Bool) -> Void) {
        //Do the authentication
    }

    private func retriveUserData(callBackMethod: (data: String, Success: Bool) -> Void) {
        //Gets the data and passes processed data back in a callBackMethod
    }

    func doAuthentication(callBackMethod: (Success: Bool) -> Void){
        GETMethod { (Success) in

            if Success {
                self.retriveUserData({ (data, Success) in


                    data // <- HOW DO I GET THIS INTO LOGIN VIEW CONTROLLER?


                    callBackMethod(Success: true)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}


class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    func loginButtonPressed(){
        Methods.sharedInstance().doAuthentication { (Success) in

        }
    }

}

class NextViewController: UIViewController {

    //Present data when it becomes available
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a MVC pattern, especially the "model" part.  Create an object that serves as the shared data model for your application.  Update it when you have new data.  Depending on the timing of updates vs. controller loading, it can either send notifications when data changes or provide an API that the interested objects (controllers) can query to find out the current state.